# Linked list function works when called normally, but doesnt work when called in an IF statement?

Tags: c, linked-list

So firstly I have IntListInsert which simply populates the list

```
void IntListInsert(IntList L, int v)
{
    assert(L != NULL);
    struct IntListNode *n = newIntListNode(v);
    if (L->first == NULL)
        L->first = L->last = n;
    else {
        L->last->next = n;
        L->last = n;
    }
    L->size++;
}
```

Then I have another sorting function
If I simply call IntListInsert like this, it populates the lists properly, although not sorted.

```
void IntListInsertInOrder(IntList L, int v)
{
    
        IntListInsert(L, v);
}
$./list 1 2 3
123
```

When I try an IF statement to **handle empty lists**, It only inserts the first object in the list...

```
void IntListInsertInOrder(IntList L, int v)
{
    //check if list is empty
    if (L->first == NULL) {
        IntListInsert(L, v);
    }
}

$./list 1 2 3
1
```

Greatly appreciate any input :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you call the IntListInsertInOrder function?
I think the problem is `if (L->first == NULL)` is only true for the first input `1`.
After u assigned `1` to the list `if (L->first == NULL)` is false.

Comment: This seems to be the issue, can you recommend a way to ensure the full list gets populated after L->first is no longer NULL?

Comment: Yes of course, but why do u check if the list is empty at all? I dont unserstand the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

After you've inserted your first value, L->first is no more NULL and the if prevents from inserting other values ? The full code would be usefull

Comment: This seems to be the issue, can you recommend a way to ensure the full list gets populated after L->first is no longer NULL?

Answer (score 0):

The function `IntListInsert`  appends only one node in each its call.

When the passed list is empty the function sets the pointer `first` of the list to the newly created node.

```
if (L->first == NULL)
        L->first = L->last = n;
```

So after exiting the function `L->first` is not equal to `NULL`.

On the other hand the function `IntListInsertInOrder` calls the function `IntListInsert` only when the list is initially empty.

```
void IntListInsertInOrder(IntList L, int v)
{
    //check if list is empty
    if (L->first == NULL) {
        IntListInsert(L, v);
    }
}
```

So what you are doing is what you are getting.